# Send JSON file in HTTP (VB6)

Tags: json, http, post, vb6

I can now able to send the pure text in HTTP using this code..

```
Public Function WebRequest(url As String, jsonFile As String) As String
    'In this string, I am putting the parsed JSON file
    jsonFile = ReadTextFile(jsonFile)

    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    http.Open "POST", url, False
    http.send jsonFile

    WebRequest = http.responseText
    Set http = Nothing
End Function
```

This function is just to parse the JSON file, I have CommonDialog control for choosing the file.

```
Public Function ReadTextFile(sFilePath As String) As String
   On Error Resume Next

   Dim handle As Integer
   If LenB(Dir$(sFilePath)) > 0 Then

      handle = FreeFile
      Open sFilePath For Binary As #handle
      ReadTextFile = Space$(LOF(handle))
      Get #handle, , ReadTextFile
      Close #handle
   End If

End Function
```

That simple code will successfully POST a text in HTTP, but what I want is to post the exact JSON file, not just the text inside of it.

Comment: Er, JSON *is* text.  That's the entire point of it, it is a textual serialization format for a simple data hierarchy.  No idea what you might be trying to ask for.  Does the server expect `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or some other encoding rather than just `text/json` or `application/json` maybe??

Comment: @Bob77 on my code, only the text inside of json file is posted on HTTP, what I want is the exact file of JSON to be posted on HTTP because we have a naming convention of JSON file for some purpose.

How someone would check  the name format of my generated JSON file if only the text not the JSON file is sent on HTTP

Comment: Still unclear what you're looking for. If your server is expecting a filename, you'll have to describe how it's expecting it to be sent.

Comment: Are you talking about posting to a URL endpoint with the same name as the json file?  Or does it need to send it as a file upload rather than a json doc?